# Databricks - "Alter Table Owner to userid" is not working with Spark.sql in Pyspark notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

**I am trying to run the below command in spark sql in my pyspark notebook (databricks) and it is getitng an error but the same command is working in sql notebook.**

```
ALTER TABLE sales.product OWNER TO `john001@mycomp.com`;
```

**Pyspark Code below**

```
  source_sql = "ALTER TABLE sales.product OWNER TO `john001@mycomp.com`;"

  spark.Sql(source_sql)
```

**running the above print statement in spark.sql is throwing an error as shown below**
----> 7   spark.sql(source_sql)

```
        /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
            707         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
            708         """
        --> 709         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
            710 
            711     @since(2.0)

        /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
           1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
           1304         return_value = get_return_value(
        -> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
           1306 
           1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:
```

but if I run the same in %sql in the cell - it is working.

can someone suggest on how to run the same in spark.Sql("ALTER TABLE sales.product OWNER TO `john001@mycomp.com`;")

Comment: have you started cluster with table ACLs enabled for Python as well?

Comment: yes, we checked the box under Table Access Control and enabled below.

Enable table access control and only allow Python and SQL commands

Answer (score 0):

[Spark SQL's ALTER TABLE command](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html) does not have the OWNER TO option.  This is what's being executed in your pyspark code, and why it fails.

[Databricks' ALTER TABLE command](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html) *does* have this option; it is a different SQL dialect.  This is what's being executed in your sql notebook, and why it succeeds.